# Solving $e^{iz} = 1+i$, where have I gone wrong?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to solve a question which asks to find all the solutions of $e^{iz}=1+i$. Here is what I have done:

$z = x + yi$
$e^{i(x+yi)} = 1+i$
$e^{xi-y}=1+i$
$e^{xi-y}=\sqrt2e^{(\frac\pi4 +2n\pi)i}$
$e^{-y}=\sqrt2$
$y=-\frac12ln2$

$x=\frac\pi4 +2n\pi$

$Z = i(x+yi)$
$Z = i((\frac\pi4 +2n\pi)+ (-\frac12ln2)i)$
$Z = \frac12ln2 + (\frac\pi4 +2n\pi)i$

The correct answer according to the marking scheme is:
$Z = (\frac\pi4 +2n\pi) - i\frac\pi4$

This differs slightly from my answer. Could someone please explain where I have gone wrong in my working?

Comment: Probably two mistakes: 1. Why is your $z=x+iy$ becoming $Z=i(x+iy)$? 2. Did you copy faithfully the *imaginary part* of the solution $z$ proposed in your solutions sheet?

Comment: oops! I copied out the wrong answer. Sorry, my bad. It was silly of me to add the extra i. Thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct except for the extra $i$ you wrote. The answer is
$$ z = x + i y = (\pi/4 + 2n \pi) + i ((-1/2) \ln 2).$$ 
You can check this answer is correct by plugging it in: Since
$$iz = (1/2) \ln 2 + i (\pi/4 + 2n \pi),$$ 
we do have
$$
e^{iz} = e^{(1/2)\ln 2} e^{i(\pi/4 + 2n \pi)} = \sqrt{2} e^{i(\pi/4 + 2n \pi)} = 1 + i$$
The answer $z = (\pi/4 + 2 n \pi) - i \pi/4$ in the marking scheme is wrong, because you can check to see you get
$$iz = \pi/4 + i (\pi/4 + 2n \pi),$$
so
$$
e^{iz} = e^{\pi/4} e^{i(\pi/4 + 2n \pi)} = e^{\pi/4} (1 + i)/\sqrt{2},$$ 
which does NOT equal $1 + i$.

Comment: oops! I kind of copied out the wrong answer. The correct answer is indeed the correct one. It was silly of me to put the extra i. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: I just came across other similar questions, but with some modifications using the absolute notation. Example, $e^z=|1+i|$, $|e^z=|1+i|$, $e^{|z|}=|1+i|$ and $e^{i|z|}=|1+i|$. I am completely lost here - I do not understand how to approach these kinds of problems. Could you please guide me on how to solve these? I would really really be grateful. Thanks